# Is there a Cydia tweak that gives the camcorder its own button?

Tags: ios, video, jailbreak, camera, cydia

I have an HTC One V in addition to my iPhone. One thing I love about it is the camera application. It has two buttons: one to capture a photo, and another to capture a video.

[image: HTC Sense: One button for photos, another for videos]

I love that you don't have to toggle between them and wait a second or two while it switches. That second or two could cause me to miss the funny things my kids are doing at that moment.

Is there a jailbreak tweak that brings this same sort of functionality to iOS?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. But you can leave it on video, then tap the camera button on screen to take a picture during your video.

Comment: Hmm... That's actually a good point. Maybe I'll start doing that.

Comment: It would be much nicer if the hardware buttons could be configured to snap a picture rather than ending your video.

Answer (score 1):

This is a four step process that takes less than 3 seconds for me on iOS 6 - so I don't know if anyone's going to tweak this in jailbreak.

1. Press the sleep wake button to lock the screen (or wake the screen if the phone is off).
2. Press and swipe up on the camera icon on the lock screen.
3. Decide if you want video or photo and examine the toggle where you initially pressed the camera icon.
4. Tap the toggle if the camera isn't in the mode you prefer.
5. Tap the record button.

If you take 3 minutes to practice this, see if training your brain to know it only has to track two places on the phone speeds this up fast enough to avoid needing a dedicated button. The lock button and a very small portion of the screen are the active targets, so you might be able to optimize your speed to start recording knowing that you can start recording as fast as possible and then trim the clip later once the recording starts.